# Kotlin abstract class secondary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, class-constructors

I can't create the secondary constructor for this abstract class.

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
abstract class BaseAndroidViewModel(
        application: Application,
        private val creditsGetByIdUseCase: CreditsGetByIdUseCase,
        private val videosGetByIdUseCase: VideosGetByIdUseCase,
        private val reviewGetByIdUseCase: ReviewGetByIdUseCase,
        private val addToFavoritesUseCase: AddToFavoritesUseCase,
        private val getFavoriteByIdUseCase: GetFavoriteByIdUseCase
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

constructor(application: Application) : this(application) // There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain error
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call secondary constructor like this -

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") abstract class BaseAndroidViewModel : AndroidViewModel{
constructor(application: Application,
            creditsGetByIdUseCase: CreditsGetByIdUseCase,
            videosGetByIdUseCase: VideosGetByIdUseCase,
            reviewGetByIdUseCase: ReviewGetByIdUseCase,
            addToFavoritesUseCase: AddToFavoritesUseCase,
            getFavoriteByIdUseCase: GetFavoriteByIdUseCase) : super(application)

constructor(application: Application) : super(application) }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create a **secondary** constructor, and a class has non empty **primary** constructor, you should pass all parameters that **primary** constructor has, e.g.:

```
abstract class BaseAndroidViewModel(
        application: Application,
        private val creditsGetByIdUseCase: String,
        private val videosGetByIdUseCase: String
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    constructor(application: Application) : this(application, 
            "creditsGetByIdUseCase", "videosGetByIdUseCase") // here we pass other necessary parameters
}
```

In your case it might be the following:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
abstract class BaseAndroidViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val creditsGetByIdUseCase: CreditsGetByIdUseCase?,
    private val videosGetByIdUseCase: VideosGetByIdUseCase?,
    private val reviewGetByIdUseCase: ReviewGetByIdUseCase?,
    private val addToFavoritesUseCase: AddToFavoritesUseCase?,
    private val getFavoriteByIdUseCase: GetFavoriteByIdUseCase?
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    constructor(application: Application) : this(application, null, null, null, null, null)
}
```

Or you can create **primary** constructor with default parameters:

```
abstract class BaseAndroidViewModel(
        application: Application,
        private val creditsGetByIdUseCase: CreditsGetByIdUseCase? = null,
        private val videosGetByIdUseCase: VideosGetByIdUseCase? = null,
        private val reviewGetByIdUseCase: ReviewGetByIdUseCase? = null ,
        private val addToFavoritesUseCase: AddToFavoritesUseCase? = null,
        private val getFavoriteByIdUseCase: GetFavoriteByIdUseCase? = null
    ) : AndroidViewModel(application) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a `cycle in the delegation calls chain error`, is because

```
constructor(application: Application): this(application)
```

Is the equivalent to java:

```
public MyClass(Application application){
    this(application)
}
```

This said you are calling your constructor recursively.

---

As stated in [Alok Mishra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088521/1797950), you should instead make a call to the super constructor.

```
constructor(application: Application): super(application)
```

That is actually the equivalent of your primary constructor:

```
BaseAndroidViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application)
```

You can constate that this is just a replacement of keywords `constructor` by `BaseAndroidViewModel` and `super` by `AndroidViewModel`